# how to authenticate for internal and external users

Tags: c#, .net, sql, iis

In my application I have a login page. I want this login page to appear only to the external users. Internal users should directly go to the application using windows sign information. So, if external users click on the link a login page must open.
If internal users click on the link it has to direct to the application without authentication.
I can do the login part for external users. I need help with internal users. Just give me an idea.

Comment: Define 'internal'? Like on the same network? Some specific subnet? Some particular haircolor?

Comment: If the company's name is XYZ123. Internal user will be test@XYZ123 or the network of XYZ123.

Comment: NTLM, ActiveDirectory, LDAP, Certificate

Comment: could you please send me some links that i can read to understand the process?